# How to OR null value in Apache Solr query?

Tags: solr, sql-null

The last option to solve this for me was to ask StackOverflow.

I am trying to create a Solr query to get documents that have a specific value on one of its fields OR that does not have a value...

Theorically, this query should have worked.

Here is some information:

**Query:** (name: john) --> Result count: 15383 //Johns

**Query:** (name: {* TO *}) --> Result count: 61013  //People that have a name

**Query:** -(name: {* TO *}) --> Result count: 216888 //People that do not have a name

Now, when I use first and third query in a same query with OR operator, I expect to get (216888 + 15383) results. But SOLR gives 15383 results, simply ignores the effect of third query:

**Query:** +((name:john) (-(name:{* TO *}))) //This is the query I was used.

Is this a bug of Solr or am I doing wrong in query? Merging two query results is an additional solution but I do not want to do extra code implementation if I could do it with a simple query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`(-name:[* TO *] AND *:*) OR name:john`

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks. Would you be able to explain what `AND *:*` does in this example? I see that my search doesn't work if I leave that part out, I'm just not sure why.

Comment: `*:*` means all rows. `*:* -name:*` means all rows without a name value. `name:john OR (*:* -name:*)` can be translated into SQL as `name='john' OR name IS NULL`

Comment: This type of answer really deserves/requires an explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it like this.

```
&fq=name:john OR !name:['' TO *]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below to get results which is null and rest

```
-name:[* TO *] OR *:*
```

Answer (score -1):

try the below query -

```
q=(name:john OR -(name:[* TO *]))
```

Comment: I found the solution in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343794/searching-for-date-range-or-null-no-field-in-solr)

Comment: -(-(name:john)+(name:{* TO *}))