# Search Null and a particular value in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a column COUNTRY AS

```
<field name="COUNTRY" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true">
```

I need to search value of country as usa or blank value but I am not able to do it.

I have tried

```
fq=country[ U]

fq=country['' U]

fq=country[NULL U]
```

but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers to these previous questions

- [How to OR null value in Apache Solr query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672259/how-to-or-null-value-in-apache-solr-query)
- [Searching for date range or null/no field in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343794/searching-for-date-range-or-null-no-field-in-solr)

You should be able to use one of the following:

```
 -(-(country:usa)+(country:{* TO *})) 

 (-country:[* TO *] AND *:*) OR country:usa
```