# Lucene query for range of field or its absence

Tags: solr, lucene

Being new to Lucene I'd like to find documents where a certain field is either within a given range or entirely absent.  That is I'd like to combine the results of these two queries:

```
q=something AND field:[lower TO upper]
q=something AND -field:[* TO *]
```

Either query gives me the desired result but when I try to combine the two I get nothing:

```
q=something AND (field:[lower TO upper] OR -field:[* TO *])
```

`something` can be a more complex query.  Actually, my query will be Solr query from within a Java program in case it makes a difference.  How can this be done?

Comment: Check -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343794/searching-for-date-range-or-null-no-field-in-solr And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query/

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Indeed that works.  So the answer is `q=something AND NOT (-field:[lower TO upper] AND field:[* TO *])`.  Now I wonder how expensive is such a query?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
q=( (+something -field:[* TO *]) OR (+something +field:[lower TO upper]) )
```