# What's wrong with this Solr range filter query?

Tags: search, solr, solr-query-syntax

The following filter query returns zero results (using *:* as query):

```
-startDate:[* TO *] OR startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]
```

But if I filter only by:

```
-startDate:[* TO *]
```

I get 3 results.

If I filter only by:

```
startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]
```

I get 161 reults.

Why is the combined FQ returning zero results? What I want is the filter to return any doc whose start date is null or start date is before today.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Solr 4.2.1.2013.03.26.08.26.55

**EDIT:**

Well, strange it may sound a colleague suggested putting parenthesis on the two parts like this:

```
(-startDate:[* TO *]) OR (startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY])
```

And somehow it worked. I'm still curious why that made a difference. Hope someone can shed some light.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching for date range or null/no field in Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343794/searching-for-date-range-or-null-no-field-in-solr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solr supports pure negative queries.  They do this, essentially, by expanding the pure negative to something like:

```
*:* -startDate:[* TO *]
```

However, what you combine it in a BooleanQuery, I don't believe it applies this sort of logic anymore.  A negative query does not, in lucene, fetch anything, but rather filters out matches brought in by other, positive, query terms.  This differs from SQL queries, which in a sense start with an implicit `*:*`, or a full table of results, and allow you to pare it down.

I believe your `OR` is effectively being ignored, since it doesn't, strictly speaking, make sense in context.  Generally, `OR` is just syntactic sugar, I believe (`field:this OR field:that` is equivalent to `field:this field:that`).

So, in effect your query is:  `startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY] -startDate:[* TO *]`, which makes the results you see more obvious.  When you wrap it in parentheses, then each term query is treated separately, and you gain access to `solr`'s support of lonely negative queries.

---

A much better idea is to store a default value, if you need to search for unset/null values. `*:*` and by extension pure negative queries like this have to scan the entire index, and so perform very poorly.  Providing a default value will improve performance, and prevent this sort of confusing situation.

Comment: I think this is what is happening. A did a "debug" query and it is translated to startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY] -startDate:[* TO *], which indeed doesn't make sense. I do think a default value is ideal, but the support for null is only temporal while the index is populated again (with non-null values).

Answer (score 0):

I used [femtoRgon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17225534/1497) and was able to construct a query that included a range and blank values.

The following includes all docs with a StartDate on or after 1/1/2014 and all docs without a StartDate.

```
(StartDate:[2014-01-01T00:00:00Z TO *]) OR (-StartDate:([* TO *]) AND *:*)
```

The magic is `(-StartDate:([* TO *]) AND *:*)`.  This will select the docs without a StartDate.

Answer (score -1):

Pure negative queries don't work, because they are omitting results from nothing.

Try:

*:* AND -startDate:[* TO *]

Comment: Please notice that I'm trying to figure out a filter query (fq param) so negative queries should work OK.

Answer (score -1):

When you query with `-startDate:[* TO *]` you get documents which do not have any data for the `startDate` field.

When you query for `startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]` you get documents which have a value less than or equal to `NOW/DAY+1DAY` in the `startDate` field.

You could try `-startDate:* OR startDate:[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]`. The first part says documents that do not have a value and the second part says document having value less than or equal to `NOW/DAY+1DAY` in the `startDate` field.

Comment: Seems that -startDate:* behaves as -startDate:[* TO \*] does. I mean, if I set fq as -startDate:\* I get 3 results. If I set fq as -startDate:* OR startDate:[\* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY] I get zero again.