# Solr FQ : syntax for OR operator

Tags: filter, solr, logical-operators

OR condition is not working for me. Filter Query I am using is:

```
fq=+(field1:true OR field2:[1 TO *])
```

Individual:

1. fq=+(field1:true)
2. fq=+(field2:[1 to *])

This works just fine. 
But ORing of these two conditions is not working as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `+`?

Comment: + is I guess for mandatory clause.

Comment: I did, it's not working! :(

Comment: What happens if you just use `fq = field1:true OR field2:[1 TO *]` ? It should work, this is the right syntax.

Comment: You can also try something like `fq = +field1:true +field2:[1 TO *]`.

Comment: yes, tried that as well. Still no luck. Following is the output  with debugQuery=true.

<arr name="filter_queries">
<str>
ads_f13003:true OR inv_strlocqty_10151_10552:[1 TO *]
</str>
</arr>
<arr name="parsed_filter_queries">
<str>
ads_f13003:true inv_strlocqty_10151_10552:[1.0 TO *]
</str>
</arr>

Comment: Please explain the difference of results between the 2 queries !

Comment: 1. There is no difference in the resultset. The filter is not working as per expectation.
2. can't use fq = +field1:true +field2:[1 TO *] because that is AND operator equivalent

Comment: An update:
1) fq=field1:true OR field2:false  =>works just fine.
2)fq=field1:true OR field2:[1 TO *] => does not work. 

So the new problem statement is:  "OR operator with one of the expressions as range query does not work."

Comment: Try your query with parenthesis: `fq=(field1:true) OR (field2:[1 TO *])`. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221736/whats-wrong-with-this-solr-range-filter-query)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding parenthesis did not work :(

fq=(field1:true) OR (field2:[1 TO *]) --> did not work!! :(