# Solr OR returns no results on valid subqueries

Tags: solr

I have a Solr query that looks up docs that have no values for a field/field does not exist AND fields that contain values from a given set (A OR B OR C).

What I came up with was (-field:[* TO *] OR field:(A OR B OR C)). Each subquery returns expected results but combining the two with an OR returns me nothing. Is there another way to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221736/whats-wrong-with-this-solr-range-filter-query), you can add **parenthesis** and try something like:

```
(-field:[* TO *]) OR (field:(A OR B OR C))
```