# Remove Expired Records in solr query syntax

Tags: lucene, solr, date-math

I'm having a solr query syntax issue (I think) with solr 1.4. I'm trying exclude expired records from a solr query. However if the record doesn't have an expiry record, i would like to bring that record back also. E.g.

To only get a list of record that haven't expired i am using this query:

```
expirydate:[NOW/DAY TO *]
```

Then I thought to get a list of records which **don't** have an expiry date i can use

```
-expirydate:[* TO *]
```

Both queries work on their own. I.e. the first query brings back 3 records. The 2nd query brings back 921 records. However when I combine the 2 queries together with an **OR** I get 0 records:

```
expirydate:[NOW/DAY TO *] OR -expirydate:[* TO *]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure here, but I don't think you can combine OR with the negation operator in this manner.

Try adding a dummy field with the same value in every document and try

```
enddate:[NOW/DAY TO *] OR (dummy:yes -enddate:[* TO *])
```

Comment: Wicked.. that totally works. Thank you. I already have a field i can use which doesn't change. +1

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in Solr? Or am i just not using the syntax correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to tackle this problem, I went about implementing the approved answer but then realized that I could just do this:

> -expired-date:[* TO NOW]

That worked regardless if the document had expired-date set.