# Solr OR query for different combination of facets

Tags: syntax, solr, faceted-search

I have a sample Solr schema as follows

```
  isPublic = boolean
  source = facebook| twitter | wordpress
```

I want to write a query which returns all documents from the index which matches either the isPublic = true or isPublic is false and source= facebook. Something like this

```
 solrUrl/?q=blah&fq=(isPublic:true OR (isPublic:false AND source:facebook))
```

Is such a thing possible or should I search the index two times with each of these conditions and then combine + de-duplicate the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can run such a filter query, but I think that particular query will not get you the results you're looking for, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query) about it. A logically equivalent query would be: `isPublic:true OR source:facebook`