# Solr query behaviour

Tags: syntax, solr, lucene, edismax

I have a Solr installation that contains recipes.

Each recipe has multiple ingredients and I'm currently building a recipe search that you can type 'includes/excludes' and then I have a homebrew weight system that comes in after this.

The query building is off however and so needs refining.

```
// Works perfect - 109 results
ingredients:chicken OR tomatoes OR bacon

// Down to 7 results - Definitely wrong
ingredients:chicken OR tomatoes OR bacon AND -ingredients:garlic
```

I've tried building this query any which way but can't figure out an acceptable 'fuzzy filter'

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query

Comment: not so much, I dont know how to apply that to my query

Comment: it seems to be the same issue... have you tried all the suggestions? have you read the solr-user thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
ingredients:((chicken OR tomatoes OR bacon) AND NOT garlic)
```

This works for me.

You can add all excludes like this:

```
ingredients:((chicken OR tomatoes OR bacon) AND NOT (garlic OR peanuts OR spinach))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you. You can see the search working over at http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/recipe-search/search

Answer (score 0):

Try `ingredients:chicken OR tomatoes OR bacon AND (-ingredients:garlic)`

I am assuming that you are you are using Solr 3.1 with `edismax`.

I have found that enclosing negative queries in parenthesis works. I have not had the time to look into this in more detail and figure out if this is the expected behaviour or is it a bug. If you investigate this in more detail and confirm that this is a bug, then please open a Jira issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR).

Note that the query I suggested above will search for tomatoes / bacon in the default field(s) as per your config. If you want to search for them in `ingredients` only, then use `ingredients:(chicken OR tomatoes OR bacon) AND (-ingredients:garlic)`