# How do I do a boolean OR in solr?

Tags: php, drupal, solr

I am completely new at this...

I am using durpal with the apachesolr module.

I have the following filter:

```
(  tid:19895 OR tid:19937 ) AND  type:poster"
```

This does not return any results, but if I have the following, it returns the results as expected

```
(  tid:19937 ) AND  type:poster"
```

EDIT: This is all in a filter. I need to have a list of tids that it could be along with having type be poster. So it has to be type:poster AND one of the following tids: 19895, 19937

Answer (score 2):

although:

((tid:(19895 OR 19937)) AND type:poster) should work irrespective of defaultOperator being OR/AND

adding the clauses as separate filter is better, so add two filters as

tid:(19895 OR 19937)

type:poster

should filter out the results working as AND and also cache the results for this filter separately for improved query performance for new queries using this filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think its important to note that SOLR isn't a database.  Its a search engine and therefore isn't going to work like a database query you may be used to.

adding a + means the field is required

```
+tid:19895 would mean that TID field is required to equal exactly 19895
```

The * is the wildcard so adding it means your field would contain the value but not necessarily equal the value.

```
tid:19895* would mean TID field contains 19895
```

It looks like the issue is defining the field twice in the same filter???

*So try removing the second "tid:"*

In my testing I did this:
My SOLR query is:

```
+type:poster
```

And the Filter is:

```
tid:19895 OR 19937
```

Here is another stackoverflow question similar to yours since you obviously have a different syntax than I use.

[using OR and NOT in solr query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query)

Comment: Tried your rewrite and it didn't work. I looked at that page before posting this and it didn't help me.

Comment: I had my logic messed up.  * is the "wildcard" so leaving it off means an exact match.

Comment: No. It ends up returning all posters (type:poster)

Answer (score 0):

As FYI if defalut boolen clause is "OR" then  give the query like this 
**((tid:(19895 19937)) AND  type:poster)**   This working fine i tested

Comment: well I think for some reason the default is AND... that seems to be the way it is working

Comment: In `schema.xml` you can override the default with `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>`.

Comment: if default is and means((tid:((19895)OR(19937))) type:poster) if you need more deatils about this means i can help you...