# Weird Solr/Lucene behaviors with boolean operators

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm crashing into a weird behavior with - operators in Solr/Lucene query syntax. 
If I execute the query

```
-text AND -text
```

I get all expected results (lot), but if I put some parenthesis like

```
-text AND (-text)
```

or

```
(-text) AND (-text)
```

then I get no results at all. I can't understand why. 
Do you have an explanation for this behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using OR and NOT in solr query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question have been answered very well in
[Solr mailing list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Weird-behaviors-with-not-operators-td3323065.html#a3331018). They have also added an entry in the offical FAQ, that says:

> Boolean queries must have at least one "positive" expression (ie; MUST or SHOULD) in order to match. Solr tries to help with this, and if asked to execute a BooleanQuery that does contains only negatived clauses *at the topmost level*, it adds a match all docs query (ie: *:*)
>
> If the top level BoolenQuery contains somewhere inside of it a nested BooleanQuery which contains only negated clauses, that nested query will not be modified, and it (by definition) an't match any documents -- if it is required, that means the outer query will not match.

So expressions with only "negative" values return always 0 results, except at the topmost level, where the parser silently add a `*:*` at the beginning of the query.

Therefore `-text AND -text` is transformed to `*:* -text AND -text` and so it has results, while
`(-text)` isn't transformed to `(*:* -text)`, because it is not at the topmost level, and so `(-text)` gives no results.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation depends on the search-handler you are using and the whole query string.

For example: you can search on multiple fields, like

`text AND text` <- which searched in all (default) fields - depending on the search handler

`FIELD1:text AND text` <- which uses `AND` to search inside FIELD1

`FIELD1:text1 AND (-text2)` <- searches (as i remember right) for text1 in FIELD1 AND NOT text2 in all other (default) documents - depending on the search handler.

I think, using `()` changes the scope / fields of the search.

Maybe the behaviour you describe hast to do with something like that?!

Comment: My default field is called "fulltext". The behaviour does not change if I write fulltext:text instead of text...