# Apache Solr Not Query with braces

Tags: solr, lucene

Im am trying to do a simple solr query with AND and NOT conditions.

In the first query the conditions are with braces the second query does not contain braces.

In my opinion solr should return in both cases the same result. But the first query does not return any results. The second query works perfectly. Can you explain what i am doing wrong?

```
 1st query=   q=name:*user* AND (-id:368 AND -id:367)
 2nd query=   q=name:*user* AND -id:368 AND -id:367
```

In the bug mode the parsed query looks like.

```
   +name:*user* +(-id:368 -id:367)
   +name:*user* -id:368 -id:367
```

I am using Solr4 from the daily builds apache-solr-4.0-2012-03-07_10-16-14 and its working on a tomcat. The files got index through the dhi.

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/11c26g08cg/simplification-of-boolean-query-failed

Comment: BTW () are parens, not braces.

Comment: +1 for Mauricio's link, also see http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not/ from Lucene committer hossman

Comment: I found another solution as well in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363819/weird-solr-lucene-behaviors-with-boolean-operators now that I got the right keywords :-) Thank you very much @MauricioScheffr and jpountz