# weird filter behavior in Lucene 5

Tags: lucene

in `Lucene 5`, `Filter` is deprecated in favor of `ConstantQuery` wrapping the normal query object. I came across a case where the "translated" query object from the old filter object does not work as I expected.

```
val directory = new RAMDirectory()
val config = new IndexWriterConfig(new KeywordAnalyzer())
val writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config)
writer.addDocument({
  val document = new Document()
  document.add(new StringField("k", "v1", Field.Store.YES))
  document.add(new StringField("k", "v2", Field.Store.YES))
  document
})
writer.addDocument({
  val document = new Document()
  document.add(new StringField("k", "v1", Field.Store.YES))
  document.add(new StringField("k", "v3", Field.Store.YES))
  document
})
writer.commit()

val reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory)
val searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader)

val filter =
  new BooleanQuery.Builder().add(
    new BooleanQuery.Builder()
      .add(new ConstantScoreQuery( new TermQuery( new Term("k", "v1") ) ), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
      .add(new ConstantScoreQuery( new TermQuery( new Term("k", "v2") ) ), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)
      .build()
    ,
    BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT
  ).build()

Console.println("filter: " + filter)
val results = searcher.search(filter, Int.MaxValue)
Console.println("# results: " + results.totalHits)

val filter2 = new BooleanFilter()

filter2.
  add({
    val inner = new BooleanFilter()
    inner add(new TermFilter(new Term("k", "v1")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    inner add(new TermFilter(new Term("k", "v2")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)
    inner
  }, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)

Console.println("filter2: " + filter2)
val results2 = searcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), filter2, Int.MaxValue)
Console.println("# results2: " + results2.totalHits
```

Output in the console is,

```
filter: -(+ConstantScore(k:v1) -ConstantScore(k:v2))
# results: 0
filter2: BooleanFilter(-BooleanFilter(+k:v1 -k:v2))
# results2: 1
```

From my perspective, I think `filter` and `filter2` should work the same in `Lucene 5`, but obviously the result tells otherwise. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to come from this SO Post,

[Weird Solr/Lucene behaviors with boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363819/weird-solr-lucene-behaviors-with-boolean-operators?rq=1)

Quoted as follows,

> Boolean queries must have at least one "positive" expression (ie; MUST or SHOULD) in order to match. Solr tries to help with this, and if asked to execute a BooleanQuery that does contains only negatived clauses at the topmost level, it adds a match all docs query (ie: *:*)
>
> If the top level BoolenQuery contains somewhere inside of it a nested BooleanQuery which contains only negated clauses, that nested query will not be modified, and it (by definition) an't match any documents -- if it is required, that means the outer query will not match.

So in brief, I think I have to add a `MatchAllDocsQuery` to the `BooleanQuery.Builder` so that there is at least one `MUST` or `SHOULD` clause in place to make the query actually match something (otherwise there always would be nothing). `filter` modified as below does the trick.

```
val filter =
  new BooleanQuery.Builder().add(
    new BooleanQuery.Builder()
      .add(new ConstantScoreQuery( new TermQuery( new Term("k", "v1") ) ), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
      .add(new ConstantScoreQuery( new TermQuery( new Term("k", "v2") ) ), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)
      .build()
    ,
    BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT
  ).add(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD).build()
```