# Solr parenthesis and negation

Tags: solr, lucene

Why do these solr queries yield different results?

1. `/select/?q=-id:abc OR -id:def`
2. `/select/?q=-(id:abc) OR -(id:def)`
3. `/select/?q=(-id:abc) OR (-id:def)`

1 and 2 yield the answer I expect (all documents with abc and def removed)

however 3 yields no results. Why is 3 incorrect and what is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

Boolean queries must have at least one "positive" expression (ie; MUST or
SHOULD) in order to match.

I think, using () changes the scope / fields of the search.
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363819/weird-solr-lucene-behaviors-with-boolean-operators)