# Solr / Lucene - Why is this OR query failing when the two individual queries succeed?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr document schema with with a `solr.TrieDateField` and noticed this boolean query (not authored by me) which I thought could benefit from some simplification;

```
q=-(-event_date:[2011-12-02T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW/DAY+90DAYS] OR (event_date:[* TO *]))
```

which means *events within the next 90 days or non-events* (See [Pure Negative](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser) for Solr boolean `NOT` notation) . My simplification looked like

```
q=event_date:[2011-12-02T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW/DAY+90DAYS] OR -event_date:[* TO *]
```

As stated, this didn't work (0 results). So as a test I ran the two sides of my modified OR query individually and the sum of the two results (both non-zero) equaled the sum of the original query and I can't come up with a good explanation why. Running with `debugQuery=true` didn't present anything helpful. 
I've put this on solr-user, will post back with any solutions.

Comment: Do an explain on both queries, likely both are doing different things (you query are complicated for me)

Comment: possible duplicate of [using OR and NOT in solr query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query)