# Query for solr empty field

Tags: solr, lucene

I am having a list of profiles in solr, indexing with some empty fields (e.g.: country/category etc).

```
<arr name="country">
    <str>185</str>
</arr>
<arr name="category">
    <int>38</int>
</arr>
```

I want to search profiles with no country. I used `-country:['' TO *]` as country is a string field.

Now how can I check it for an integer field? The field may be empty (no field) or with value 0. I tried `category:0` but it is not giving me the correct output, output is empty in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For string type of field you could query like

```
-country:* OR country:""
```

It'll give you all the Solr document which doesn't have country field at all. Or country with **empty string**.

For integer type field

```
-category:* OR category:0
```

It'll give you result with empty(no field) or with value 0.

There is an issue with Solr OR and NOT search. Please refer to [using OR and NOT in solr query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query) for a better understanding of **OR** and **NOT** query.