# Basic Solr query syntax

Tags: solr

All:

I want to ask one beginner question about solr query:

right now, there are Several situations I want to search:

```
[1] Search all documents with "fund" AND without "report"
[2] Search all documents with "fund" OR without "report"
```

Could any one tell me how to write these queries? 
I tried:

```
fund OR -report
fund AND -report
```

but both queries return same results

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why this doesn't work as is, but if you use the logical negation of #2, and negate that, then it does work, e.g:

```
-(-fund AND report)
```

The results for #1 `(fund AND -report)` are correct.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query), it seems that Solr has difficulty interpreting queries containing `OR` where one of the criteria is negative, but works well with purely negative queries.

FYI, you can also use `NOT` in place of `-` if that makes things easier to understand:

```
NOT(NOT fund AND report)
```

Comment: Could you help me with a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827347/plus-sign-in-solr-query-is-not-correctly-treated

Comment: Just answered. Please accept this answer if it works for you. Thanks!