# plus sign in solr query is not correctly treated

Tags: solr

All:

I am new to Solr, when I play with solr example with importing some random document,  I use a search query in q like:

```
fund+report
```

There is no space between fund and +, and I thought it will search a word "fund+report" in the document, which rarely happen in document, but a lot results return, thequery url is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=fund%2Breport&fl=id+filename+%5Bexplain%5D&wt=xml&indent=true
```

I thought Solr treat my query just like:

```
fund report
```

or

```
fund OR report
```

Could anyone tell me why solr treat my query like that? And how can I make solr treat fund+report as a single word?

Thanks

Comment: You are using ColdFusion, right?

Comment: @David Faber No, just the admin page with solr example

Comment: OK. FYI, you can change the default boolean operator in the configuration of your Solr collection so that `fund report` would be seen by Solr as `fund AND report` rather than `fund OR report`. You can also configure how close the terms should be to one another, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP call will simply translate the `+` to a space . If you need an actual `+` sign then you need to use the URL-encoded value for `+` (which I think is `%2B`). If you are looking for the **phrase** *fund report* then you want to put double quotes around the phrase, e.g., `"fund report"`. These should also be URL-encoded (I think the value for that is `%22`).

Keep in mind that if you're using stemming then a search for `"fund report"` will find results for `"funds reports"`, `"funding reports"`, etc. But maybe that is what you want.

So after all is said and done, your URL might look like the following:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=%22fund%20report%22&fl=id,filename,%5Bexplain%5D&wt=xml&indent=true
```

Note that the fields listed for the `fl` parameter should be comma-delimited. I am not sure why you have the square brackets around the `explain` field.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually what I want to find out is [1] why the input of fund+report can not treated as a single word "fund+report",(is it a solr admin demo bug?) [2] How to make solr treat it as fund+report without double quoted it?

Comment: Double-quoting is how one searches for phrases is Solr. I'm not aware of any Solr type that looks for a phrase if double quotes are not surrounding it - and I'm not sure that you would want one either!

Comment: Are you actually searching for `fund+report`, that is, with a literal `+` sign in the document itself?

Comment: Yes, the input is exact fund+report, with+sign and no space between fund and +sign, without double quote.  I want to find out why solr can not understand my input?

Comment: I think what you would need in that case is a field type that doesn't tokenize on the `+` sign, in which case `fund+report` would be viewed as a single word. However, you would still be the question of how to pass the `+` sign in the query since that character has a specific meaning to Solr (as well as to HTTP which is why it would have to be URL-encoded). According to this page, you can escape it with a backslash: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

Comment: If you're querying Solr via URL, you'll want to encode both the backslash and the plus sign `+`: `%5C%2B`, e.g: `fund%5C%2Breport`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to remove `+` signs when indexing that field, then just search for `fundreport` (which is just one word and probably would not see much stemming).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. But I still confused what the solr interpret my input into? Does it interpret it into fund OR report?

Comment: @Kuan, if you haven't made any changes to the configuration for this collection, then yes, Solr will interpret `fund+report` as `fund OR report`. The reason for this is that the HTTP call will change `+` to a space ` ` and by default, the boolean operator for your Solr collection is `OR`. You can change that configuration but you can't prevent the HTTP call from using space where you use `+`. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is also what I guess. But do you know where I can find official document to (verify/proof) that? I may need to show it to someone

Comment: I don't know where you can find "official" documentation that a `+` sign in a URL indicates a space. On Solr itself, see here for information on the standard query parser: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

Comment: So the whole thing will be I input fund+report, then the browser turn this into fund%2Breport, then after the server saw fund+report, the server think what I input should be "fund space report", and give "fund space report" to  solr query handler, and finally the query handler thought it is fund OR report?  BUT!!! from the chrome debug console, I see the browser do convert the plus sign into %2B, I wonder why the server still think I send fund space report?

Comment: when I check the url in chrome console, the browser did turn + into %2B, why the server still think that should treat as a space?

Comment: I can't explain that, sorry.

Comment: NVM, thanks a lot for helping me so much. I will keep searching and please let me know once you have some update thought.

Comment: @Kuan, if you can't accept the answer above, would you at least upvote? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what upvote(I do not mean this word's meaning but what this action means) means?

Comment: Click on the up arrow over the number next to the answer - indicating that the answer has been useful to you.